# Asp.net core 2.0 error updating model posted via ajax

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am sending a Post using ajax for my controller to update the records of a product, but I get the following error:

> "The instance of entity type 'Produtos' cannot be tracked because
>   another instance with the same key value for {'Cod'} is already being
>   tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity
>   instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using
>   'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the
>   conflicting key values."

my knowledge is still very limited and I do not know what I am doing wrong.

Here is where I load the data on the screen for editing:

```
[HttpGet]
public PartialViewResult EditaProduto(int cod)
{
    var produtos = new Produtos();
    if (cod != 0)
        produtos = _petalertaContext.Produtos.Where(c => c.Cod == cod).SingleOrDefault();

    return PartialView("_ProdutoCadAlt", produtos);
}
```

Here is where I create or update the product in the database:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult GravaProduto([FromBody] Produtos produto)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            int codShop = Convert.ToInt32(new UserLogado(this.User).PegaDados("cod"));
            produto.Codshop = codShop;

            Produtos prodAtual = _petalertaContext.Produtos.Find(produto.Cod);
            string strResp = "Produto alterado com sucesso!";

            if (prodAtual == null)
            {
                strResp = "Produto adicionado com sucesso!";

                prodAtual = _petalertaContext.Produtos.Where(c => c.Nome.ToUpper() == produto.Nome.ToUpper() && c.Codshop == codShop).SingleOrDefault();

                if (prodAtual != null)
                    return Content("Erro: Você já possui o produto " + produto.Nome + " cadastrado!");

                _petalertaContext.Add(produto);

            }
            else
            {
                _petalertaContext.Update(produto); //<== ERROR
            }

            _petalertaContext.SaveChanges();
            return Content(strResp);
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
        {
            return Content("Erro ao gravar produto: " + ex.Message + " : " + ex.InnerException?.Message);
        }
    }

    return Content("Erro: Não foi possível gravar o produtoes!");
}
```

Thanks for any help, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it has to do with this line:

```
 Produtos prodAtual = _petalertaContext.Produtos.Find(produto.Cod);
```

You already have `produto` so you don't need to get it again.

I would just do this:

```
produto.Codshop = codShop;
DbEntityEntry<Produtos> entry = _petalertaContext.Entry(produto);
entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
_petalertaContext.SaveChanges();
```